# Did Bill Clinton have his office rearranged according to Feng Shui ideas?

Tags: united-states, bill-clinton

According to a contestant of a [2005 Chinese English Speaking Contest](https://youtu.be/ELnblnr41RU?t=30m44s):

> And I guess some of you still remember when the previous American president, Bill Clinton, when he first became president, he actually had his office rearranged according to Feng Shui ideas.

Is that true?

Comment: So many filthy Oval Office sex jokes..... must resist......

Comment: He did rearrange his office ... not due to Feng Shui ... but to make  [certain other activities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewinsky_scandal) more convenient.